# Local Server - Apache redirecting all requests to /index.php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, virtualhost, mac

I'm having a weird redirect problem on my local server. I have a VirtualHost set up:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/iMac/Sites/index.php"
    ServerName jordan.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/jordan.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/jordan.local-access_log" common  
    <Directory "/Users/iMac/Sites/index.php">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing `http://jordan.local` works fine. However, when I attempt to access a subdirectory `jordan.local/somefolder/index.php`, the page shown is `jordan.local/index.php`. I do not have an .htaccess file and have restarted apache numerous times.

Apache version: 2.2.22 (Unix)
Mac OS X 10.7.5

Here's my host file if it's any help:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
#74.208.10.249 gs.apple.com
127.0.0.1       jordan.local
```

All of the local URL's I accessed (that are non-existent) showed up in my custom access logs as a 200 response code.

My Apache error logs are giving this warning:
`Warning: DocumentRoot [/Users/iMac/Sites/index.php] does not exist`
Although `/Users/iMac/Sites/index.php` is a valid path.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `DocumentRoot` to point to a directory, not a file. Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot

> **DocumentRoot**
>
> *DirectiveDescription*:   Directory that forms the main document tree visible from the web
>
> *Syntax*: `DocumentRoot directory-path`
>
> *Default*:    `DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs`
>
> *Context*:    server config, virtual host
>
> *Status*: Core
>
> *Module*: core
>
> This directive sets the directory from which `httpd` will serve files. Unless matched by a directive like `Alias`, the server appends the path from the requested URL to the document root to make the path to the document.
>
> Example:

```
 DocumentRoot /usr/web
```

> then an access to `http://www.my.host.com/index.html` refers to `/usr/web/index.html`. If the directory-path is not absolute then it is assumed to be relative to the `ServerRoot`.
>
> The `DocumentRoot` should be specified without a trailing slash.